# Should I use Object-oriented approach in designing database tables in this case

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-design, object-oriented-database

Scenario: 
I'm running tons of crawled images through a face-recognition api, the returned json has so many nodes that I had to divide all the fields into multiple tables if I enumerate the fields. e.g. following is one of the tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `face_landmark_info_nose` (
        `face_id`                  VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        `pic_id`                    INT(11) NOT NULL,
        `nose_contour_left1_x`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `nose_contour_left1_y`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `nose_contour_left2_x`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `nose_contour_left2_y`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `nose_contour_left3_x`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `nose_contour_left3_y`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `nose_contour_lower_middle_x`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `nose_contour_lower_middle_y`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `nose_contour_right1_x`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `nose_contour_right1_y`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `nose_contour_right2_x`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `nose_contour_right2_y`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `nose_contour_right3_x`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `nose_contour_right3_y`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `nose_left_x`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `nose_left_y`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `nose_right_x`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `nose_right_y`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `nose_tip_x`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `nose_tip_y`     DECIMAL(10, 6),
        PRIMARY KEY ('face_id, pic_id')
    );
```

Later I noticed most fields are in a pattern of x value and y value for a single point, so I'm thinking maybe I could design a Point table like below:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `facepp_point` (
        `face_id`                  VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        `pic_id`                   INT(11) NOT NULL,
        `x_value`                  DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `y_value`                  DECIMAL(10, 6),
        `point_name`               VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY('face_id, pic_id')
    );
```

Although by doing this, the program will be easy to maintain in the future, there are more or less 130 points like this in total for one face in one image and I would have to open one mysql query for each of them to present all the info on the website on the detail page, so should I enumerate all the fields or use the object-oriented fashion in designing the tables? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why not use the MySQL [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)?

Comment: I don't understand your reference to object-oriented but I disagree with the "program will be easy to maintain in the future" part. I find it more confusing and harder to grasp. Are available nodes expected to change many often?

Comment: "_I would have to open one mysql query for each of them to present all the info on the website on the detail page_" - no. That's what `JOIN` is for. Further - you can group points, for example `NOSE_POINT`, `EYE_POINT` etc. I wouldn't split `POINT` out to another table - this seems to add nothing to normalization.

Comment: My superior suggested that I should flatten the json data into separate fields in tables when I crawled them, otherwise I would have to write a lot of decoding on the server side I guess. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález sorry if I didn't make it clear, it was a third-party api and I find it a huge burden to write the ddl, I'm not sure if it will change if the future, if it does, maintaining the tables will be a pain, so I thought of normalizing them into points using OO concept.

Comment: @BoristheSpider thanks, I'm pretty much a novice in OO programming and databases, sometimes it baffles me as to how much I should abstract matters and whether it made sense as an object.

Comment: this question is a better fit on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: But [Object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) basically means "objects that contain data and code". What does that have to do with the database structures you're proposing?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález as of now the server side code(python django) pretty much syncs with the database tables, if I designed the tables in a more abstracted way, after running migrate, the models on django would generate code based on what my database structures looks like, thus affecting the way I implement the project, so it could be more like oop.

Comment: I don't think of this as OO.  You need only one SQL to get the 130 values:  `SELECT * FROM facepp_point WHERE face_id = ...` -- You will get 130 rows of 5 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally whether you use attributes or a new table with depends on what kind of relation the 2 have to each other.

In your case I definitely say yes.

You have a 1 to many relation (1:n) it will be much better to keep one id for each point as attribute. Your point table would likely only exist out of an id and x and y value though. I don't see a reason to give it a name or add face_id or pic_id.

Now depending on whether a face always has the same amount of points (and the name matters) you would either add a point_id for each needed point as an attribute to the face table.
Or if the order doesn't matter you give the point table a face_id and link it that way. (this way you don't have a bunch of attributes for no reason in the face table)

This might be a bit simplified, i don't know the exact workings of your use case. But in general you look at whether it is a 1:1, 1:n or n:n relationship and base your decision on that.

Comment: Thanks, I paid little thought to the relational part. I think I will adopt the grouping points approach as Boris suggested.